# UWSGI socket changes group and refused connection, resulting in 502 bad gateway

Tags: django, sockets, nginx, uwsgi

I'm running a Django app with NGINX/UWSGI.

I call uwsgi :

```
/home/rootadmin/.virtualenvs/data_collection/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/sites/data_collection_project.ini
```

**data_collection_project.ini**:

```
[uwsgi]
project = data_collection_project
base = /data_nfs/data_collection_project

chdir = %(base)
home = /home/rootadmin/.virtualenvs/data_collection

module = data_collection_project.wsgi:application
master = true
processes = 2

socket = /data_nfs/data_collection_project/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
```

As a result, a `.sock` is created. Using `ls -l` I see the socket as

```
srw-rw-rw-  1 rootadmin rootadmin        0 Jul 30 12:24 data_collection_project.sock
```

At this point, my site works fine. At some point, which I've been unable to pinpoint, my website starts retuning `502 bad gateway` to each request. At this point, i found that the group of the `.sock` changed to `www-data`

```
srw-rw-rw-  1 rootadmin www-data         0 Jul 30 12:25 data_collection_project.sock
```

At this point, my nginx error.log also raises this error:

```
2017/07/30 12:25:34 [error] 1940#0: *652 connect() to unix:///data_nfs/data_collection_project/data_collection_project.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: client_ip, server: my_ip, request: "GET  /admin/binaryQuestionApp/point/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///data_nfs/data_collection_project/data_collection_project.sock:", host: "my_website_", referrer: "https://my_website/admin/binaryQuestionApp/"
```

I do not know why/ from where this change happens. My website used to run fine for the month i've been using it. Yet, today, i ran a `sudo reboot` for the first time and ever since this happens. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my own future reference, or anybody else having a similar problem.

The issue was in having a system wide UWSGI running, alongside the UWSGI in the virtual environment. The system wide version has emperor mode enabled, which results in the system wide version taking control of the application running in the virtual environment, which in turn results in all the configurations and python-home directories being way off.

For me, the solution is simple. `sudo service uwsgi stop` in the system wide version, to simply get rid of the issue. If you need both instances running, look into disabling emperor mode.